# Any Faster alternative to FFplay

Tags: bash, shell, audio, ffmpeg, sh

I am trying to use this concoction of commands to create active noise cancellation. The thing that slows it down is the ffplay, I have tried all the different flags but there is still about a 1/2 second delay

```
rec -c 1 -t wav - | ffmpeg -i pipe:0  -af "aeval='-val(ch)':c=same" -f wav - | ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay  -
```

Is there any solution to this or is it something that is inherently slow and no alternative. I know it is not the filter that slows it down because I have done some testing and filtered a 5 minute song in about 3 seconds. I would love to get any possible help.

My Os  is MAC

Comment: If the problem really comes from the player, you could try [aplay](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay), which is part of ALSA, to see if there is some speed improvements. (see: https://superuser.com/a/511672/807246)

Comment: Hey @TGrif i'm on mac so I can't use Aplay are you aware of anything else.

Comment: Hi @WiNtEr_IcE, maybe you can try with *any* other audio player available on your mac, (yes I'm curious about the results...) I hear [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) is maintained for your os.